# How to create a full screen command line app for Windows XP

Tags: windows

I'm trying to create an app that will be used to launch other applications. It will be a command line app to launch other command line apps. I would like this app to start full screen when launched (not a window, but literally take over the entire screen. I'm targeting Windows XP but I plan to eventually make it cross platform, so it would be nice to know if there are differences between operating systems.

I don't know anything about creating windows applications, but I do know how to create a command line application.

What do I need to know/learn/do in order to create a full screen command line application?

Answer (score 0):

Have you see Far manager ( http://www.farmanager.com/download.php ) - if you think about something like this you need study console API
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682087(v=vs.85).aspx

If you want just process command line options and pipeline input/output then good news - it is the same as for linux or any other platforms:

```
int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    std::cout << "Hello world" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Will do same things for linux, freebsd, windows...

Comment: Thanks for the link to the documentation. I think this might be what I am looking for: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686028(v=vs.85).aspx Now I just need to figure out how to use it.